# why this angularjs ng-model not update to the right value?

Tags: angularjs

```
function buildControl($scope){
    $scope.test_obj = {
        used:3,
        data:[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}]
    };
}

<div ngApp>
    {{test_dict.used}}
    <select ng-model="test_obj.used">
        <option ng-repeat=" d in test_obj.data" value="{{d.id}}">{{d.id}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

why the selector always select the first option while I expect it will select the third one which's value equal 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ng-value` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/bateast/LsEL5/

HTML:

```
<option ng-repeat=" d in test_obj.data" ng-value="d.id">{{d.id}}</option>
```

JS:

```
function buildControl($scope){
    $scope.test_obj = {
        used:3,
        data:[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}]
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I make a stupid mistake, what a terrible day! In fact, the reality code if quit complex, like:<span ng-repeat="argument in focused_suite.__execution_argument_list__">
                            {{argument.Name}}:
                            <select ng-model="argument.__option__.id" ng-options="option.id as option.Record_Value for option in all_exec_args_dict[argument.id].__option_list__">
                            </select>
                            <br/>
                        </span>

Answer (score 7):

And you can also use `ng-options` directive to do that:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="buildControl">
    {{test_obj.used}}
    <select ng-model="test_obj.used"
            ng-options="d.id as d.id for d in test_obj.data"></select>
</div>
```

#### Demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SGCNHv13lmvonuMYCgDN?p=preview).

Comment: This is really what you should use, avoid `ng-repeat` implementations.